# Running 1 procedure twice using a single procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is run from a SSRS report, my problem now is that I need to include data from the previous year in the report. I wanted to be able to run the report once with the set of parameters an than a second time with the previous years data to include into my report to be able to compare the data line by line. What I have is creating an error. I am somewhat new at SQL Server, any help is much appreciated. This is built in SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE 
   @StartDate datetime,
   @EndDate datetime,
   @iClientID int,
   @iServiceLevelID int

SET @StartDate = '1-1-13'
SET @EndDate = '12-30-13'
SET @iClientID = null

SET DATEFIRST 7

DECLARE @DATA table(iclientID int,
                    sClientCode varchar(8),
                    sClientName varchar(50),
                    sServiceLevelName varchar(50), 
                    DeailyProductionAverage float, 
                    CorrectionPercentage  float, 
                    AverageAging float, 
                    decProduction float, 
                    EffectedDate datetetime, 
                    RepID int,
                    FirstName varchar(50), 
                    LastName varchar(50), 
                    Completed float)

insert into @DATA
exec procSSRS_ClientPerformanceNew_2  @StartDate, 
                                      @EndDate, 
                                      @iClientID, 
                                      @iServiceLevelID

insert into @DATA
exec procSSRS_ClientPerformanceNew_2 dateadd(year, -1, @StartDate)
                                     dateadd(year, -1, @Enddate)
                                     @iClientID
                                     @iServiceLevelID
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'year'.

Comment: I advise you to use the ISO 8601 format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` when entering date literals, . This is always interpreted correctly, no matter what your DB settings are. Whereas '1-1-13' is not immediately clear; it could potentially be `Y-M-D` (13 Jan 2001) or `D-M-Y` (1 Jan 2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, when passing an argument to a stored procedure, the argument can be either a constant or a variable. It cannot be e.g. a mathematical expression, nor can it be a function call.

So, in order to call the procedure again with the different data range, you will need to store the results of `dateadd` calls to variables and use those as arguments. For instance, you could re-use `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` for that if their original values are not needed later:

```
...

set @StartDate = dateadd(year,-1,@StartDate);
set @EndDate = dateadd(year,-1,@Enddate);

insert into @DATA
exec procSSRS_ClientPerformanceNew_2  @StartDate, 
                                      @EndDate, 
                                      @iClientID, 
                                      @iServiceLevelID
;
```

or you could declare two more `datetime` variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the commas in your parameter list when you call the procedure second time. Change your code to this to make it work:

```
exec procSSRS_ClientPerformanceNew_2

dateadd(year,-1,@StartDate),
dateadd(year,-1,@Enddate),
@iClientID,
@iServiceLevelID
```